# What is the term for a type of residence when I live at my relatives' place?

Tags: translation

I'm translaing a CV from Russian to English. There is an item on applicant's residence type. I translated two other options as *Owned* and *Rented* (Собственное жильё и Арендованное жильё in Russian), but I can't figure out the term for the kind of tenure in the subject case (in Russian, that would be Жильё родственников).

Comment: I think you will have to use a non-equivalent structure like 'live with relatives'.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of information that should NOT be on a CV, especially nowadays, owing to non-discrimination related laws, and owing to the fact that recruiting is now done by email rather than snail mail. So add an email, and avoid the problem altogether by not giving any indication of where you reside (except the City / State / Country as appropriate).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok, but "at relatives' place" doesn't necessarily mean "with them", they might own the place but reside somewhere else. Can I emphasise that somehow?

Comment: What Denis said.  But there is no well-defined term for "lives with parents" in US English (other than, perhaps, "lives with parents").

Comment: 'live in accommodation owned by relatives'.

Comment: "Own", "rent", or, "squat" would be the only way to cover all the bases. If you don't own your residence, "rent" is enough information for a CV.  (They don't need to know that you're not paying anything.)

Comment: Do you actually need to say who owns the premises where you live? Presumably you pay some token rent, sufficient for you to say that you live at 'rented premises'. Is it anyone else's business who you rent from?

Comment: "Room and board provided by relatives".

Comment: I agree that such information does NOT BELONG on a CV that is used as a résumé. If you were working in that city, say so. If you were not working, don't even mention that period.